# They could help me demonstrate by induction a divisibility

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, discrete-mathematics

Shows that $3^{n+1}$ divides $2^{3^{n}} + 1$ for each integer  $n \geq 0$.

I have the inductive base which is
prove that it is true for

$ n \in \mathbb{N}$

$3^{(1)+1}$ divides $2^{3^{(1)}} +1 $

$\frac{9}{9}$ is true

now I proposed that it is true for  $n=n+1$

$3^{(n+1)+1}$ divides  $2^{3^{(n+1)}} + 1$

how can i continue with the demonstration, help please

Comment: Hint: $$2^{3^{n+1}}=\left(2^{3^n}\right)^3.$$

Comment: thank you very much, it helped me a lot